pthread_cond_broadcast not waking up threads waiting with pthread_cond_wait
I'm just facing a problem with my threads. I'm coding a program that needs to execute asynchronous tasks, and I do it via a thread pool.
To avoid my threads running in the void when they have nothing to do, I block them with pthread_cond_wait then when a new task arrives I wake one up with pthread_cond_signal.
I specify that I have the obligation to use C++98 so I don't have access to the std::thread lib, that's why I use the C functions.
On MacOS everything works perfectly and I haven't detected any problem for the moment.
Here is my class ThreadPool:
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

class ThreadPool {
public:
    ThreadPool(size_t numThreads);
    ~ThreadPool();

    void    enqueueTask(void (*function)(int, int), int client_fd, int backend_fd);

    void    kill();

private:
    std::vector<pthread_t> workers;
    std::queue<void (*)(int, int)> tasks;
    std::queue<std::pair<int, int> > taskArgs;

    pthread_mutex_t queueMutex;
    pthread_cond_t condition;
    bool stop;

    static void* workerThread(void* arg);
    void run();
};

And here is my implementation:
ThreadPool::ThreadPool(size_t numThreads): stop(false)
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&queueMutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&condition, NULL);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {
        pthread_t worker;
        pthread_create(&worker, NULL, workerThread, this);
        workers.push_back(worker);
    }
}

ThreadPool::~ThreadPool()
{
    if (!stop) {
        this->kill();
    }   
}

void    ThreadPool::kill()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&queueMutex);
    stop = true;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&condition);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueMutex);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < workers.size(); ++i) {
        pthread_cancel(workers[i]);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < workers.size(); ++i) {
        pthread_join(workers[i], NULL);
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&queueMutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&condition);
}

void    ThreadPool::enqueueTask(void (*function)(int, int), int client_fd, int backend_fd)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&queueMutex);
    tasks.push(function);
    taskArgs.push(std::make_pair(client_fd, backend_fd));
    pthread_cond_signal(&condition);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueMutex);
}

void    *ThreadPool::workerThread(void* arg)
{
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
    pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED, NULL);

    ThreadPool* pool = (ThreadPool*)arg;
    pool->run();
    return NULL;
}

void    ThreadPool::run()
{
    while (true) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&queueMutex);

        while (!stop && tasks.empty()) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&condition, &queueMutex);
        }

        if (stop) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueMutex);
            return;
        }

        void (*task)(int, int) = tasks.front();
        std::pair<int, int> args = taskArgs.front();
        tasks.pop();
        taskArgs.pop();

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueMutex);
        
        pthread_testcancel();

        task(args.first, args.second);

        pthread_testcancel();
    }
}

My problem is the following, on linux (at least Ubuntu), when I call my function ThreadPool::kill() to stop all threads pthread_cond_broadcast does not wake up the threads and they remain blocked on pthread_cond_wait making the main thread wait for them to join them with pthread_join blocking the program completely, and the only way to stop it is to send a SIGKILL to the process.
Here is an example:
bool running = true;

static void interruptHandler(int sig_int) {
    (void)sig_int;
    running = false;
}

void task(int a, int b)
{
    size_t i = a + b;
    size_t r = 0;

    for (; i < 1000000; i++)
        r = a + i;
    sleep(1);
    std::cout << "task done: " << r << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    ThreadPool *pool = new ThreadPool(4);

    signal(SIGINT, interruptHandler);

    while (running)
    {
        sleep(1);
        pool->enqueueTask(task, 0, 0);
    }

    pool->kill();
}

When I hit CTRL+C the process becomes completely dead can only be stop sending SIGKILL...
Note that I'm using PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED because I my threads to end their task before being canceled, but the problem seems not to to come from some kind of blocking task because if i do
int main(void)
{
    ThreadPool *pool = new ThreadPool(4);

    signal(SIGINT, interruptHandler);

    while (running)
        ;

    pool->kill();
} 

the problem is the same.
I do not understand why linux has this behavior and how to deal with it and solve the blocking.
Thank you for your help.

There are probably multiple problems here, especially since there is no standard notion of threads and atomics in C++98 and because signal behavior is largely implementation-defined, but for one your signal handler violates the requirements of a signal handler, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal. You need to make running a volatile sig_atomic_t.

Any reason why you can't use a newer standard?

Anyway, for good measure declare private copy constructor and assignment operator with no definitions to prevent wierd use-after-free and double-free problems. Rule of big 3 still applies.

It looks like pthread_cond_broadcast correctly wakes up all threads. The problem is in cancelling them (with pthread_cancel): Function pthread_cond_wait is a cancellation point, and if a thread is cancelled here, it (re-) acquires the mutex! So, the first thread is cancelled successfully, but all other threads cannot acquire the mutex because it is hold by the already-dead thread. You need to register a cleanup handler for solve that problem.

Even after solving this, it is worth thinking about whether you really want to pthread_cancel in C++ (like oil in water). If the thread could be unwinding (e.g. if exceptions are ever thrown in the codebase), and could be in a destructor (e.g. if the codebase ever uses RAII), you have a crash https://godbolt.org/z/31ndKKqY1 . And if you intend to upgrade to C++11, the problem is worse.

Remove the call to pthread_cancel and it should work fine.  Having a global stop flag checked by all the threads means you don't need cancellation.

Thank you very much for your help!
Removing the pthread_cancel solved the problem, I didn't know that canceling the thread made the thread exit pthread_cond_wait, and that logically by continuing it tries to reacquire the mutex

The first rule of pthread_cancel() is "never call pthread_cancel()". Thread cancellation is bad news.  Instead provide means to make your threads stop cooperatively, or else just terminate the whole program, threads and all, by calling exit().
